# How to Display Images From JSON in Android

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-imageview

**I got json data with image url. Now I want to get images from that image url from json data. So, how can i get image from that image url? Any suggestion for this?**

I get following image url from json.

```
[{....,"image":"xyz.net/abc/img/p/9/0/9/7/9097-tonytheme_product.jpg",....},{....}]
```

I want to display above image url on dynamically created imageview. 
I have following method for dynamially created imageview.

```
public void addImagesToView() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Log.i("ArrayList In Image","" +arraylist);
    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {

        imageButton = new ImageView(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        // for setting image margin and spacing(left,top,right,bottom)
        params.setMargins(60, 20, 5, 5);
        imageButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        horizontalOuterLayouthome.addView(imageButton);

        // horizontalOuterLayouthome.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
}
```

Comment: Use [Universal ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: This is the most straight forward thing I've ever seen, and I'm using this now: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {

        imageButton = new ImageView(this);

        Bitmap bitmap = loadImage(arraylist.get(i));
    imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        // for setting image margin and spacing(left,top,right,bottom)
        params.setMargins(60, 20, 5, 5);
        imageButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        horizontalOuterLayouthome.addView(imageButton);

        // horizontalOuterLayouthome.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
```

**loadImage** function

```
protected Bitmap loadImage(String utl2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.v("utl2--", utl2);
        URL imageURL = null;

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            imageURL = new URL(utl2);
        }

        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: @user2009847 can you give me one image url.

Comment: @user2009847 i think url is incorrect. k i guess your getting url from `JSON` print that in log and give

Comment: all json data get properly in logcat but i can't display in imageview.

Comment: @user2009847 ya i found that what is the problem..before that url add this **`http://`** and try.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

        final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
        copy(in, out);
        out.flush();

        final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        //options.inSampleSize = 1;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
    } finally {
        closeStream(in);
        closeStream(out);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: ms. Monika it could help but not without loader to set in implemetation class..............But nice efforts

Comment: this code generate some syntex error in "IO_BUFFER_SIZE", "copy(in, out);", "finally {
         closeStream(in);
         closeStream(out);
     }"

Comment: i already use this code but i m not success. Could not load Bitmap from:"path"

Answer (score 1):

Use below code of image loader class with image adapter.....

```
public class ImageLoader {

    int image_size = 60;
    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    Context m_c;
    boolean mFlag = false;

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        m_c=context;
    }

    //  final int stub_id = R.drawable.animation_loding;

    public void DisplayImage(String url,Bitmap my_bmp, ImageView imageView, int ad_b_width, boolean b) 
    {
        this.mFlag = b;
        this.image_size = ad_b_width;
        if(url!=null)
        {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);

        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            if(mFlag)
            {
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int w1 = image_size;
                if(w > w1)
                {
                    int h1 = (h*w1)/w;
                    System.out.println("photos size :: "+w1 +"  and  "+h1);
                    //Bitmap bit = drawShadow(bitmap, 0, 1, 1, 1);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w1, h1));
                    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                else 
                {
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w, h));
                    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);

            imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.region_images);
        }
        }
        else if (my_bmp != null)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap=my_bmp;

            if (bitmap != null)
            {
                if(mFlag)
                {
                    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
                    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                    int w1 = image_size;
                    if(w > w1)
                    {
                        int h1 = (h*w1)/w;
                        System.out.println("photos size :: "+w1 +"  and  "+h1);
                        //Bitmap bit = drawShadow(bitmap, 0, 1, 1, 1);
                        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w1, h1));
                        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w, h));
                        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) 
    {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        // from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // from web
        try 
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
            .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) 
    {
        try 
        {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = this.image_size;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            Log.i("images scal ", String.valueOf(scale));
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable 
    {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) 
        {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() 
        {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
            {

                if(mFlag)
                {
                    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
                    int w = bitmap.getWidth();

                    int w1 = image_size;


                    if(w > w1)
                    {
                        int h1 = (h*w1)/w;
                        System.out.println("photos size :: "+w1 +"  and  "+h1);

                        photoToLoad.imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w1, h1));
                        photoToLoad.imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                        photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        photoToLoad.imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w, h));
                        photoToLoad.imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                        photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }

                    bitmap = null;
                }
                else 
                {
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    bitmap = null;
                }
            }               
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }
```

Comment: and in which you want to show image set loader   imageLoader.DisplayImage(String_imageurl, null, imgg_view, imgeSize, false);

Comment: which place i use this class? means in current activity class shall i use this java class?

Answer (score 1):

use Universal Image Loader it is good diaplay and cache the images https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

```
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(a, "your folder");

 // Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
 imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
 // Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
 ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
      // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
     .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
     .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
     .enableLogging()
     .build();
 // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
 imageLoader.init(config);
 options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
 .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_id)//display stub image
 .cacheInMemory()
 .cacheOnDisc()
 .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
 .build();

 ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageview); 
 imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, image,options);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rich said [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is a good option if you are receiving the url from JSon, it loads the image in a background async task very fast and easy to implement, for example:

```
String imageUrl = "xyz.net/abc/img/p/9/0/9/7/9097-tonytheme_product.jpg"; // this is an example, you can get this url from json
Picasso.with(this.getActivity()).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

And that's it.